Why could not convert string to float: 'Switzerland'
i was trying to do my lab exercise but there is error but i dont know whats the problem and where show i fix it. can anyone show me whats the problem so i can fix it? this is the code:
f, ax = plt.subplots (figsize = (10, 10))
sns.heatmap (df.corr (), annot = True, linewidths = .5, fmt = '.1f', ax=ax)
plt.show ()

and then this output show up:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 2
      1 f, ax = plt.subplots (figsize = (10, 10))
----> 2 sns.heatmap (df.corr (), annot = True, linewidths = .5, fmt = '.1f', ax=ax)
      3 plt.show ()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Switzerland'


The problem is because Switzerland is landlocked, not an island, so it does not float in the ocean, y'see.

this isnt your entire code, sth is missing, where is Switzerland coming from?

this isnt your entire code, sth is missing, where is Switzerland coming from?

it seems that you may have defined sns as something incorrect as you have never defined it in the code sampled above. I am assuming that you defined sns earlier in your code
